# use a variable outside of Promise (in windows8 javascript development)

Tags: javascript, windows-8, promise

there is a code:

```
var theContent;    
Windows.Storage.PathIO.readTextAsync(filepath).done(function (fileContent) {

                    theContent= fileContent;

                },

                function (error) {

                });
```

then when I want to use 'theContent' outside Windows.Storage.PathIO.readTextAsync,
it doesn't work... theContent variable contains nothing at all.

What part of the code is wrong?
Thanks!

---

I put some part of the source which makes trouble.

**global.js** which contains namespace array variable for sharing. (in a.js and b.js)

```
WinJS.Namespace.define("GLOBAL", {
        theList: null
    });
```

**a.js** which loads text in a certain file.

```
function readTextFromFiles() {

        GLOBAL.theList= new WinJS.Binding.List();

        for (var i = 0; i < theFileList.length; i++) {

            if (theFileList.getAt(i).filepath !== null) {

Windows.Storage.PathIO.readTextAsync(theFileList.getAt(i).filepath).done(function (fileContent) {

                    var splitted = fileContent.split("\r\n");

                    for (var j = 0; j < splitted.length; j ++) {
                        GLOBAL.theList.push({
                            partA: splitted[j]
                        });
                    }


                },

                function (error) {

                });

            }
        }


    }
```

**b.js** which uses GLOBAL.theList in various ways

```
ready: function (element, options) {

            new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("#2 length " + GLOBAL.theList.length, "MESSAGE").showAsync().then();
        },
```

*Here is the problem.*
When I debug **a.js**, I see that **GLOBAL.theList** contains text of the file correctly. However, when I navigate the page to **b.html(b.js)**, the popup message shows "#2 length 0" which means that **GLOBAL.theList** contains nothing.

- I included global.js in the default.html before the page loads other .js files.
- I tested and it worked when I did not use the Windows.Storage.PathIO.... promise. (when I directly put data into the GLOBAL.theList arbitrarily)

Comment: Klados, what you are doing wrong is expecting `fileContent` to appear as soon as the `.done()` expression is executed. At that point, `...readTextAsync()` hasn't returned any data; it has returned a *promise* of data. The data will arrive asynchronously, some short time later. Therefore, your treatment of the data must be *inside* the `.done()` handler. There is generally little point in setting an outer var, such as `theContent`, to data derived asynchronously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part where you're asking for `theContent` in a straight line (procedural), rather than as a callback.

`.done(function (content) { doStuff(content); });`

Or, if `doStuff` doesn't use `this` and you don't need to do anything else with it, just `.done(doStuff);` and doStuff will be fired with the content when the content comes back.

```
loadImage = function () {}; // returns promise
showImage = function (image) {} // shows image

var imageLoading = loadImage("img/huge-img.bmp");

imageLoading.done(showImage);
```

Or to make it even cleaner, build `showImage` to use promises (subscribing to their callbacks inside of the function).

```
function showImage(promise) {
    promise.done(function (img) { 
    document.body.appendChild(image);
 });
```

Now you've got

```
 var image = loadImage("huge-img.bmp");
 showImage(image);
```

Uses promises.  Looks totally natural.

***EDIT*** *re: namespacing*

---

You're still probably not going to want to push things into a list as the only thing you do inside the callback.

What is using the list?

Is `theList.push()` a custom function which has the same name as `[].push()` but does extra stuff?

Or is it just an array of stuff?

Here's the problem:
Like AJAX callbacks, a promise doesn't wait for the thing to finish, before moving on to the next thing.

So if your program is trying to do something with that array, outside of the `done` (when the array will eventually have data), then those functions are going to be working on an empty array.

Instead, you should be using methods (callbacks) to handle the Promise's return.

```
// these both do the same thing
/* ... */ .done(function (data) { NAMESPACE.module.callback(data); });
/* ... */ .done(NAMESPACE.Module.callback.bind(NAMESPACE.Module));

// if NAMESPACE.Module.callback ***does not use `this`*** you can write
/* ... */ .done(NAMESPACE.Module.callback);
// if you are unsure for even a second, do one of the other two calls
```

If you need to do more stuff with the data in the callback, then just do something like:

```
/* ... */ .done(function (data) {
    var arr = doStuff(data);

    arr.forEach(function (obj) {
        NAMESPACE.Module.list.push(obj);
    });

    NAMESPACE.Module.callback_relying_on_list();
});
```

Notice that the 2 keys here are:

1. make sure that `this` is correct in your callbacks
2. do work inside of the promise -- the point of them is so that you don't have to set timers to see if stuff is ready, yet... so if you're just setting values and not telling anybody that they're ready, the promise isn't doing its job

**EDIT #2** *re: source*

---

Have a look at what you're doing here (simplified):

```
// a.js

function getFiles () {
    GLOBAL.list = [];
    getAsyncData().done(function (text) {
        GLOBAL.list.push({ content : text });
    });
}

//b.js
GLOBAL.Messages = {
    write : function (messages) {
        messages.forEach(/* ... */);
    },
    ready : function () { alert(GLOBAL.list.length); } }
};

// main program
getFiles();
GLOBAL.Messages.ready();
GLOBAL.Messages.write(GLOBAL.list);
```

I know this isn't your exact code, but look at that simplified situation for a minute:

What happens if my `getFiles` function works perfectly, but the server doesn't send my data back for 30 seconds?

My `ready` and `write` functions aren't going to wait for that to happen.
They're going to fire as soon as my `getFiles` is done.

So here, you've got that promise in the wrong spot.
It's 100% called the right way, but why not do this:

```
// a.js
function getFiles () {
    var filesLoaded = getAsyncData(); // I'm collecting the promise, not chaining it. 
    // again, simplified
    filesLoaded.done(function (text) { GLOBAL.list.push({ content : text}); });

    // ***super important part***
    return filesLoaded;
}


// b.js
/* ... */ = {

    ready : function (promise) {
        promise.done(function () { alert(GLOBAL.list.length); });
    },

    write : function (promise) {
        promise.done(/* write the list */);
    }
}
```

Now your main looks like this:

```
var files = getFiles(); // files is the promise
// files.done, files.then, etc

GLOBAL.Messages.ready(files); // giving the promise to the method
// ready(promise) will subscribe to promise.done

GLOBAL.messages.write(files); // so will write(promise);
```

When working with promises in this way, remember that `files` n my example is the exact same object that you were adding `.done()` to in your chain.

Also remember that sometimes your functions are going to care about the values the promise returns, and other times, the functions just want to know when the promise is done, so they can do something which needs to happen afterwards, instead of setting timers to check.

And with cleaned up functions which take promises any time you're dealing with a sync data, now you have:

```
var files = readTextFromFiles();
/* ... */.ready(promise);
```

Does it mean that you need one more function to sit between what this `ready` is doing and what your old ready looks like?

Well, yeah...

But is it worth it to know that your functions aren't going to go off early.
And it looks really clean, without the nests, while still being 100% a sync.

If you're in a rush, or you can't edit those other functions, you could do the bad idea, which would be to bootstrap stuff at the bottom of the page:

```
(function (promise) { promise.done(function () {
    /* ... everything() ... */ });
}(files));
```

Ugly and hard to pick apart and needs to be edited on separate pages, but at least it's still async and it's still doing things in order.

But it ***still*** means returning and collecting and passing the promise around.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! but I have a question that can I use Namespace variable inside the .done() expression? I mean that replacing 'theContent=fileContent' to 'MyNamespace.theList.push ({title:fileContent}); ? Because even if the 'fileContent' is filled with the right data, I cannot use MyNamespace.theList. It seems empty. @Norguard

Comment: Have a look and let me know if there's something missing, that you need to know.

Comment: I think that I missed the point of my problem. I put some part of the source and description. Thanks for your kind replies. @Norguard

Comment: @klados have a look at Edit #2.  Your problem still looks like what I mentioned earlier, just slightly more complex. The exact same solutions still apply.  Let me know if there are still issues.

Comment: I'm stuck again... actually I've tried what you suggested, but I think I am doing something wrong, a big one. Simply, I just want to 'read a text in files (in a.js)'->'store the text in some GLOBAL variable (in global.js)'->'use the stored variable in a.js, b.js etc..' but here, I cannot understand 'GLOBAL.messages.ready' and write. What does 'write' part do? what is 'main program'? there is no such thing in my codes.. just a.js, b.js, global.js. and a.js has function that reads text from file, and both a.js and b.js should use stored text. Thank you.. really a lot!

Comment: if possible, I'm wondering that would you just give me some short code which has such features? again, I just want to read file at a.js, store the text in global variable, and use the variable at a.js, b.js or even c.js wherever. best regards.